# Bash script complaining about date usage

Tags: bash

I found a [script that gets the ISS (space station) pass over information](http://vsido.org/index.php?topic=1016.msg11467#msg11467http://) and outputs to stdout online. I tried to run the script and got the following usage error for every instance that the script tried to display the time:

```
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

That was caused by the following code, as far as I can tell:

```
isspt1=$(cat /tmp/issp.json | jq -r '.response[0].risetime')
isspt11=$(date -d @"$isspt1" +'%d-%m-%Y (%H:%M:%S)')
```

Elsewhere the time failed to display but didn't return usage errors:

```
echo -e "Passing Date & Time -> $isspt11"
```

would return nothing emplace of that variable.

I have tried to research a solution for a few hours and not found how to use date properly. Since I didn't write the code and I'm not good with bash I haven't been able to solve it myself. I'd like to see this script working properly if you can help.

Comment: The php tag was suggested so I added it but don't know how relevant it is

Comment: What's the value of `$isspt1`? Could you run the script with `bash -x` or add `set -x`?

Comment: Are you sure jq is installed and running correctly?  Is isspt1 getting filled in OK?  From what I see, date is probably barfing on the contents of $isspt1 because the format string is fine.

Comment: @Biffen I'm not quite sure what you mean. It's meant to be a time, not current but in the future. Could you explain what you mean by `bash -x` or adding `set -x`?

Comment: @BJBlack I brew installed it and brew seemed happy that it was all done correctly as far as I remember. Should I just try `echo $isspt1` to check the value?

Comment: By the way did you set the `latitude` and the `longitude` in the original script?

Comment: @BitFlow I understand that it's meant to be a time, but what is its *actual value* by the time `date` gets called? Either run your script with `bash -x <script file name>` or add `set -x` to the top of the script (below the shebang, but at least above the problematic line), it will print all commands before they are run, so that you can see what arguments are passed to `date`.

Comment: Yeah.  Knowing what isspt1 is would be very helpful.  You could also jam in the command without assigning it to the variable to see if there's an error.

Comment: isspt1 holds `1472904756` after it is assigned a value, Sat, 03 Sep 2016 12:12:36 GMT

Comment: @BitFlow That works just fine with the `date` I happen to have on my machine (`date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`). Could you check *which* date you're using (e.g. `date --version`)?

Comment: @Biffen I got this from running bash -x
`++ date -d @1472904756 '+%d-%m-%Y (%H:%M:%S)'
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: @BitFlow My previous comment still applies.

Comment: @Biffen `date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]` was returned. I don't know if that's a Linux vs Mac Unix issue

Comment: @BitFlow Looks like it's not GNU then. It would seem the script was written for a `date` that follows a different specification than the one you've got. So either adapt the script or get a hold of a different `date`.

Comment: @Biffen would you have suggestion on how to do either? Changing the format to one that may work would be my preference but I haven't been able to find out how to do that from the few hours I spent so far trying to

Comment: @BitFlow The method for both is the same: Look up how to do it and then do it. Not sure with what part you'd need help.

Comment: @Biffen I'm here asking for help because after a fair amount of time I couldn't find something which explained to me how to reformat the date in a way that worked. This question thread is based around the fact that I don't understand what is wrong with the date after a non-trivial amount of research.

Comment: @BitFlow I don't agree with ‘*non-trivial*’. Have you even tried `date --help` or `man date`?

Comment: @Biffen `date --help` doesn't work for the same reason as `date --version`> I have used `man date`, search unix tutorials on date formatting and read up through both about `date -d` and not found something which has allowed me to fix the code. It may be because I lack some required knowledge about bash, I'm not good at bash, but have none the less failed having gone to the other obvious resources first. StackOverflow isn't what I default to when I cannot solve a code issue.

Comment: @BitFlow Note that this problem has *nothing* to do with Bash. What you need to do is work out how to convert an epoch time to a specified format with the `date` you have (or some other tool). Without knowing *which* `date` that is, there's not much anyone else can do to help. (Here's something, though: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-do-i-convert-an-epoch-timestamp-to-a-human-readable-format-on-the-cli)

Comment: @Biffen The BSD Unix mention in that link solved it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` usage was BSD Unix `date` so the [correct usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-do-i-convert-an-epoch-timestamp-to-a-human-readable-format-on-the-cli), that @Biffen linked to, meant that `isspt11=$(date -d @"$isspt1" +'%d-%m-%Y (%H:%M:%S)')` should have looked like:

```
isspt11=$(date -r "$isspt1" +'%d-%m-%Y (%H:%M:%S)')
```